# Javascript RegExp string pattern

Tags: javascript

I need to check JS matches for a dynamically generated string.

ie.

```
for(i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
{
 pattern_1="/part of "+arr[i]+" string!/i";

 if( string.search(pattern_1) != -1)
  arr_num[i]++;

}
```

However, this code doesn't work - I presume due to the quotes. How do I do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to match? You are correct though, if you neet to dynamically create the regex, you will need to use new `RegExp("string");`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/pattern/` literal only works as, well, a literal. Not within a string.

If you want to use a string pattern to create a regular expression, you need to create a new RegExp object:

```
var re = new RegExp(pattern_1)
```

And in that case, you would omit the enclosing frontslashes (`/`).  These two lines are equivalent:

```
var re = /abc/g;
var re = new RegExp("abc", "g");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing a string to the `search` function so it treats it as a string. Try using a RegExp object like so:

```
myregexp = new RegExp("part of " + arr[i] + " string!", "i")
if (string.search(myregexp) != -1) {
   arr_num[i]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// note you dont need those "/" and that "i" modifier is sent as second argument
pattern_1= new RegExp("part of "+arr[i]+" string!", "i");
```